# EF Core event after entities materialized from database

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-2.2

To perform operations before/after entities are written to the database, I can do so before/after `.SaveChanges()`.

How about after entities are read ("materialized") from the database - is there an event, lifecycle hook, callback, or something that I can use?

I'm upgrading a 1.x project to 2.2 and I hope there's something new that allows me to do that.

Comment: I need to perform low-level work *at the context level*, going though entity entries and so on. I'd prefer not to duplicate that in all my repositories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.1), since efcore 2.1 there is now a way to handle some events from ChangeTracker.

> State change events
>
> New Tracked And StateChanged events on ChangeTracker can be used to write logic that reacts to entities entering the DbContext or changing their state.

Maybe you can find what you want there.